# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget - How fix this error?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax-error

1/ I have a problem with this code but after 3 days I still cannot understand why.
See Picture to better understand the error (Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget Error) that software gives me.
[Error code in Android Studio program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Fik.jpg)

2/ Then I have another problem about the initialization: into void Initstate the variable visualizedText cannot be translated with the function getTranslated (it doesn't accept context). For which reason?

```
class WarmUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  WarmUpPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _WarmUpPageState createState() => _WarmUpPageState();
}

class _WarmUpPageState extends State<WarmUpPage> {
  int counter = 8;
  dynamic visualizedText; //text to be visualized above button
  Image imgButton;
  Image imgButtonUp = Image.asset("lib/images/unpressed.png");
  Image imgButtonDown = Image.asset("lib/images/pressed.png");

  //Inizialize the state of the picture into imgButtonUp
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imgButton = imgButtonUp;
    visualizedText ='Warm Up'; //initial text but I cannot translate it because context gives error
  }

  //Function to increment the counter
  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter--;
      if (counter == 0) {
        randompagegenerator(context);
      } else if (counter == 99) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup1');
      } else if (counter == 70) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup2');
      } else if (counter == 40) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup3');
      } else if (counter == 20) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup4');
      } else if (counter == 10) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup5');
      } else if (counter == 5) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup6');
      } else if (counter == 1) {
        visualizedText = getTranslated(context, 'warmup7');
      } else {}
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle _textStyleText = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 40,
    );
    TextStyle _textStyleNumber = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 70,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       appBar: ReusableBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //color: Colors.grey[850],
              //color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
              child: Center(
                child: Positioned(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: imgButton,
                    onTap:() {
                      _decrementCounter();
                      incrementAppBarCounter();
                  },
                    onTapDown: (tap) {
                      setState(() {
                        imgButton = imgButtonDown;
                      });
                    },
                    onTapUp: (tap) {
                      setState(() {
                        imgButton = imgButtonUp;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.28,
              child: Container(
                //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                //color:Colors.grey[500],
                child: Text(
                  visualizedText,
                  style: _textStyleText,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.58,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.2,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                //color: Colors.grey[200],
                child: Text('$counter', style: _textStyleNumber),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 15,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: - For [2], would be great if you could tell more about what `getTranslated ` is actually doing and what context error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For [1],

A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack, and the path from the Positioned widget to its enclosing `Stack` must contain only `StatelessWidgets` or `StatefulWidgets`, clearly you're wrapping a `Positioned()` with a `Container()` and a `Center()`